# Как сделать собственную озвучку в Яндекс Навигаторе?

Tags: навигация

Как можно сделать ("залить" в приложение) собственную озвучку в Яндекс Навигаторе? Все предложенные варианты уже испробованы и хотелось бы что-то нового, например озвучку в стиле Boston Dynamics, конечно без цензуры, как со знаменитым пылесосом, или какой-то мультяшный герой (точно не "Дракула") озвучивал бы дорогу, что явно понравилось бы моей дочери, которая иногда скучает в дороге пока я за рулем.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков почему не по теме? Я не согласен. Вполне технический вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, к чему это отнести? К программированию? Или к администрированию?) В первом варианте - декомпилировать, заменить ресурсы, собрать воедино. Во втором - подготовить пакет и залить его на целевое устройство.